# Python & Discord.py, leave command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i want to do something like that:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'leave'):
        await guild.leave()
```

But guild.leave() wont work, is there something else that work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `await message.author.guild.leave()` instead of `await guild.leave()`

Also you can use this: `await client.get_guild(guild_id).leave()`

Comment: That just does nothing and i dont know if you understood my Question correct, i want that the Bot leaves the Discord, not the Message Author

Comment: I added another way in my message, you can use it if first don't help you.

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you mark my answer as solution, to close this question?